# PHP como "desenhar" uma imagem

Tags: php, imagem

Gostaria de saber o seguinte, como posso "desenhar" uma imagem com PHP?
Vi em alguns sites, páginas PHP que fazem uma imagem na hora. O que eu quero é algo simples, apenas um fundo com borda e um texto.
Se não for possível, somente um texto simples já me contenta.

Já sei que preciso definir o `Content-Type para image/png`. Só preciso das funções para "desenhar" a imagem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pra está tarefa você pode usar o GD ou o imagemagick/imagick, exemplo de desenho com GD:

### Desenhando um retângulo com GD

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerectangle.php

```
<?php
// cria uma imagem de 200 x 200
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);

// Aloca cores
$pink = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 105, 180);
$white = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 255, 255);
$green = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 132, 135, 28);

// Desenha o retangulo com estas cores
imagerectangle($canvas, 50, 50, 150, 150, $pink);
imagerectangle($canvas, 45, 60, 120, 100, $white);
imagerectangle($canvas, 100, 120, 75, 160, $green);

header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($canvas);
imagedestroy($canvas);
```

### Transfornando uma string em texto com GD

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php

```
<?php
//Cria uma imagem de 100 x30
$im = imagecreate(100, 30);

//Desenha um fundo branco
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

// Escreve um texto
imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, 'Ola mundo!', $textcolor);

header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

### Escreve um texto com imagemagick

Requer PHP >= 5.1.3 e ImageMagick >= 6.2.4, para instalação veja: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/imagick.setup.php

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$pixel = new ImagickPixel('gray');

/* Gera a nova imagem */
$image->newImage(800, 75, $pixel);

/* Cor do texto */
$draw->setFillColor('black');

/* Fonte e tamnanho da fonte */
$draw->setFont('Bookman-DemiItalic');
$draw->setFontSize( 30 );

/* Adiciona o texto */
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 45, 0, 'Ola mundo!');

/* Define o tipo da imagem */
$image->setImageFormat('png');

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
```

Para mais detalhes veja a documentação:

- Imagick: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.imagick.php
- GD: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.image.php
- Outras APIs do PHP: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/refs.utilspec.image.php

Comment: Obrigado, só mais uma coisa...Tem como fazer quebra de linha se o texto ultrapassar o tamanho da imagem?

Comment: @Superbomber Eu não tenho certeza, não sei se é possivel, mas acho que com http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagettfbbox.php você consegue fazer isto.

Comment: Sem querer incomodar @Guilherme Nascimento   ... Mas é que o texto está aparecendo com acentos todo "bugado"...Mas eu já defini o Content-Type com codificação utf-8...Sabe o que poderia ser?

Comment: @Superbomber Salve o documento com utf-8 sem bom usando o SublimeText ou o Notepad++, se não der certo abra uma questão nova por favor, que vou testar o seu código :)

Comment: Eu já estava salvando assim, e mesmo assim acontece o erro...Eu fiz a outra questão: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73328/php-gerando-imagem-com-acentos-bugados