# PHP gerando imagem com acentos "bugados"

Tags: php, imagem

Eu estou gerando uma imagem, que é basicamente um texto simples.
Só que o texto fica com os acentos "bugados", todo incorreto, mesmo eu definindo a codificação para utf-8.
Eis o código:

```
<?php
   header('Content-Type: image/png; charset=utf-8');
   draw("Olá, como vai você?");

   function draw($text){
      $imagem = imagecreate(700, 30);
      $fundo  = imagecolorallocate($imagem, 241, 243, 240);
      $color  = imagecolorallocate($imagem, 200, 30, 30);
      imagestring($imagem, 5, 0, 0, $text, $color);
      imagepng($imagem);
      imagedestroy($imagem);
   }
?>
```

Isso é apenas uma "versão resumida" do código que quero fazer. Pois envolve mais que uma única frase...O código é apenas para exemplo do meu problema.
O `draw()` ele é executado apenas uma vez mesmo. O que varia é só o texto...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testei realmente será necessário outra função, neste caso use o [`imagettftext`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php):

```
array imagettftext ( resource $imagem , float $tamanho, float $angulo, int $posicaoX, int $posicaoY, int $cor , string $fonte , string $texto)
```

Primeiro copie uma fonte na mesma pasta do script, por exemplo `arial.ttf`:

```
<?php
define('FULL_PATH', rtrim(strtr(dirname(__FILE__), '\\', '/'), '/') . '/');

header('Content-Type: image/png');

//Cria 400x30
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

$texto = 'áéíóú';
$fonte = FULL_PATH . 'arial.ttf';

imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $black, $fonte, $texto);

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: Eu tentei dessa forma, mas aparece "A imagem contém erros e não pode ser exibida." :/

Comment: Copiou a fonte `arial.ttf` na pasta do script? @Superbomber

Comment: Sim eu copiei, peguei a fonte do Windows e servidor é Linux...Pode ser isso?

Comment: @Superbomber remove o `header('Content-Type: image/png');` veja o erro que ocorre e me avisa.

Comment: Nossa eu não tinha pensado nisso...rsrs aqui: Warning: imagettftext() [function.imagettftext]: Could not find/open font in /home/a4071498/public_html/index.php on line 39  ...Mas eu upei a fonte, veja: http://prntscr.com/7q1z34

Comment: @Superbomber então foi erro meu, faz o seguinte posta o caminho absoluto. Vou editar o script na resposta e você copia. Só 1 min

Comment: @Superbomber então foi erro meu, eu já editei a resposta, agora ele aponta o caminho completa.

Comment: Agora está ocorrendo outro erro: Warning: imagettftext() [function.imagettftext]: Could not read font in /home/a4071498/public_html/index.php on line 40  ...Pelo visto ele não conseguiu ler a fonte, talvez por ser para Windows, não sei se faz diferença...Mas se fizer, você sabe onde posso baixar uma fonte para Linux?

Comment: Mas a função `imagettftext` é pra carregar fontes ttf mesmo, isto é estranho. Vou testar no meu Debian e te aviso

Comment: @Superbomber Conseguiu encontrar o problema?

Comment: Infelizmente não...Mas não se preocupe, eu resolvi utilizar frases sem acentos. Muito obrigado. :)

Comment: Espere não desista rs, vou testar aqui, um minuto @Superbomber

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25613/discussion-between-guilherme-nascimento-and-superbomber). @Superbomber

Comment: Certo, já estou logado no chat.

Comment: @Superbomber saiu do chat? Viu a mensagem?

Comment: @Superbomber talvez este script usando `putenv` lhe ajude http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87967/3635