# Escrever em imagem com php

Tags: php, gd

Estou tentando imprimir certificados online preenchidos dinamicamente com PHP.
O código que estou usando é:

```
class Certificado
{

    public $nome_para_certificado = '';
    public $modelo_de_certificado = '';

    function __construct($nome)
    {
        $this->nome_para_certificado = $nome;
    }

    public function gerar() 
    {
        header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
        $texto = 'Certificamos que ' . $this->nome_para_certificado . ' participou do Evento nos dias 21, 22 e 23 de setembro de 2014 na Universidade Federal da Paraíba - UFPB';
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->modelo_de_certificado);
        $preto = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
        $font_path = 'http://meu-site.com/custom/TravelingTypewriter.ttf';
        imagettftext($img, 50, 0, 10, 20, $preto, $font_path, $texto);
        // imagestring($img, 5, 300, 400, $texto, $preto);
        imagejpeg($img);
        imagedestroy($img);
    }
}
```

Quando uso `imagestring` consigo imprimir o texto direitinho mas com o `imagettftext` não ta dando certo.

Preciso usar o `imagettftext` pra poder modificar tamanho de fonte e tipo também.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amigo um detalhe muito importante que precisa ser ressaltado, você usou o caminho da fonte com http:

```
    $font_path = 'http://meu-site.com/custom/TravelingTypewriter.ttf';
    imagettftext($img, 50, 0, 10, 20, $preto, $font_path, $texto);
```

O correto seria usar o caminho absoluto que está no teu servidor, supondo que no seu servidor o caminho seja:

- Se `/etc/www/custom` então use:

  ```
  $font_path = '/etc/www/custom/TravelingTypewriter.ttf';
  imagettftext($img, 50, 0, 10, 20, $preto, $font_path, $texto);
  ```
- Se `/home/htdocs/custom` então use:

  ```
  $font_path = '/home/htdocs/custom/TravelingTypewriter.ttf';
  imagettftext($img, 50, 0, 10, 20, $preto, $font_path, $texto);
  ```
- Se `c:\wamp\custom` então use:

  ```
  $font_path = 'c:/wamp/custom/TravelingTypewriter.ttf';
  imagettftext($img, 50, 0, 10, 20, $preto, $font_path, $texto);
  ```

O motivo disto está explicado na documentação [imagettftext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php):

> Dependendo da versão da biblioteca GD usada no PHP, quando fontfile não começar com `/` então o caminho do .ttf será acrescentada ao nome do arquivo e a biblioteca tentará procurar esse nome de arquivo um caminho de fonte definido na biblioteca.

Isto quer dizer que se o caminho for relativo e não absoluto, ao invés dele procurar a partir do local que está o script, ele irá procurar pelo PATH definido nas configurações do GD, então provavelmente ele pensa que `http` é uma pasta dentro da pasta de fontes do sistema.

Um truque que pode funcionar (note que neste caso é necessário remover a extensão .ttf):

```
<?php
//Define a pasta do script atual como o caminho das fontes
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));

class Certificado
{

    public $nome_para_certificado = '';
    public $modelo_de_certificado = '';

    function __construct($nome)
    {
        $this->nome_para_certificado = $nome;
    }

    public function gerar() 
    {
        header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
        $texto = 'Certificamos que ' . $this->nome_para_certificado . ' participou do Evento nos dias 21, 22 e 23 de setembro de 2014 na Universidade Federal da Paraíba - UFPB';
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->modelo_de_certificado);
        $preto = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);

        //Quando usar GDFONTPATH= não use a extensão .ttf
        $font_path = 'TravelingTypewriter';

        imagettftext($img, 50, 0, 10, 20, $preto, $font_path, $texto);
        imagejpeg($img);
        imagedestroy($img);
    }
}
```

Comment: Guilherme, muito obrigado! Suas dicas me ajudaram muito a resolver o problema. Um abraço.

Comment: Acho que agora fiz certo. Confere? Abraço.

Answer (score 4):

olha este rabisco aqui. Fiz as menores alterações possíveis.

```
<?php

class Certificado {
    public $nome_para_certificado = '';
    public $modelo_de_certificado = '';

    function __construct($nome, $modelo)
    {
        $this->nome_para_certificado = $nome;
        $this->modelo_de_certificado = $modelo;
    }

    public function gerar() 
    {
        header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
        $texto = 'Certificamos que ' . $this->nome_para_certificado;
        $texto1 = 'participou do Evento nos dias 21, 22 e 23 de setembro de 2014 na';
        $texto2 = 'Universidade Federal da Paraíba - UFPB';
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->modelo_de_certificado);
        $preto = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
        $font_path = 'arial.ttf';
        imagettftext($img, 12, 0, 10, 200, $preto, $font_path, $texto);
        imagettftext($img, 12, 0, 10, 230, $preto, $font_path, $texto1);
        imagettftext($img, 12, 0, 10, 250, $preto, $font_path, $texto2);
        // imagestring($img, 5, 300, 400, $texto, $preto);
        imagejpeg($img);
        imagedestroy($img);
    }   
}

$imagem = new Certificado("Edilson Samuel", "modelo.jpg");
$imagem->gerar();

?>
```

Tendo como exemplo esta amostra de imagem:

[image: imagem]

O Resultado impresso seria algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Há bastantes probabilidades, de o problema, ter sido gerado porque, não definiste o valor de `$modelo_de_certificado` como também pode ter sido o mau carregamento da fonte.

Quando surgem problemas como este, podes também procurar por soluções na página do [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefttext.php)

Comment: Caro Edilson, muito obrigado pela resposta muito bem elaborada e bastante didática. Suas dicas me ajudaram a resolver e o problema era exatamente o path da fonte, como voce alertou. Retirei o http e chamei a fonte a partir do path relativo: $font_path = '../custom/TravelingTypewriter.ttf'. Muito obrigado e parabéns por saber tanto sobre o assunto. Um abraço.

Comment: Obrigado eu, boa sorte.

Comment: Oi, Edilson, rejeitei uma sugestão de edição sua especialmente por ter colocado Windows e Ubuntu com marcação de código e também porque [tinha várias outras melhorias](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88652/201) que podiam ser feitas. Se puder, dê uma conferida neste meta post: [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/201) . . . Depois apago este comentário que não tem a ver com sua resposta. Saudações!