# Erro 1114 (HY000) no MySQL: The table is full

Tags: mysql

Exportei uma base de dados com uma dimensão de 14GB do MySQL de um computador com SO Windows e pretendo importá-la no MySQL de um computador com o SO Ubuntu 14.04

Utilizei o seguinte comando para exportar a base de dados "dados":

```
mysqldump -u root -p dados > teste.sql
```

Depois de exportada tentei importar a mesma no MySQL do computador com SO Ubuntu 14.04 através de:

```
mysql -u root -p dados < teste.sql.
```

Após alguns minutos de execução aparece o seguinte erro:

> ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table "XXXXXXX" is full

Como ultrapassar este erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagino que você esta usando InnoDB então confira o espaço em disco disponível para /usr que é a partição onde comumente esta a base do mysql. Se o espaço não for suficiente para importar, talvez seja melhor o local onde ele salva estas tabelas.( ibdata1, ibdata2 )

Pesquise por:
innodb_data_file_path